Evaluate $\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(2\omega\xi)\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\xi d\theta$
I know some basic properties of the Dirac delta 'function', and I'm familiar with the sifting property. In any case, I'm stuck trying to evaluate this double integral
$$
\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(2\omega\xi)\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\xi d\theta,
$$
where $r,\omega\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Here's my initial attempt.
$$
\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(2\omega\xi)\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\xi d\theta
=\left(\int\limits_{-r}^{0}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{\theta}\sin(2\omega\xi)d\xi\right)\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\theta\right)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccl}
-\frac{1}{2\omega}\sin(\omega r)\sin(2\omega r) &,&~~\text{if}~r\in(-r,0)\\
0 &,&~r\notin [-r,0]
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This does not make any sense to me since $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. My guess is that the value of this integral is zero. All suggestions are appreciated.

First integrate with respect to $\xi$:
$$
\int_{-r}^0 \int_0^{\theta}\sin(2\omega\xi)\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)\,d\xi\,d\theta
=\int_{-r}^0\frac{(1-\cos(2\omega\theta))}{2\omega}\cos(\omega\theta)\delta(\theta+r)\,d\theta. \tag{1}
$$
As discussed here and here, there is some ambiguity in the definition of an integral containing a Dirac delta when the latter is centered at the boundary. In the context of Fourier series, it's usual to define $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}f(0^+)$, in which case the result of $(1)$ would be
$$
\frac{1}{4\omega}(1-\cos(2\omega r))\cos(\omega r). \tag{2}
$$
In the context of the Laplace transform, however, it's usual to define $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\delta(x)\,dx=f(0^+)$, in which case the result of $(1)$ would be twice the expression in $(2)$.

Please note that $-\frac{1}{2\omega}sin(\omega r)\sin(2\omega r)=\frac{1}{2\omega}\left(1- \cos(2\omega r)\right)\cos(\omega r)$. In other words, we both arrive at the same result if $r\in (-r,0)$. But how does this even make any sense since $r>0$?

Why do you write $r\in(-r,0)$? The variable that must be in that interval is $\theta$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371653/double-integral-with-dirac-delta

That post is about a slightly different problem. Suppose you have an integral of the form $\int_{-R}^0f(\theta)\delta(\theta+r),dr$ (note that $r$ and $R$ are different parameters). Then the result is $f(-r)$ if $-r\in(-R,0)$, and $0$ if $-r\notin(-R,0)$. Your integral corresponds to the case $-r=-R$. In this case, the result is not well defined and depends on the context, as discussed in the posts that I mentioned in my answer.

$\int\limits_{-R}^{0}f(\theta)\delta(\theta+r)d\theta=?$

I answered this question in my previous comment.

$dr\neq d\theta$.

Sorry, you are right. That was a typo. The integral in that comment was supposed to be $\int_{-R}^0f(\theta)\delta(\theta+r),d\theta$.

OP's double integral is of the form
$$\begin{align} J~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}}\!\mathrm{d}\theta f(\theta)\delta(\theta+r)I(\theta)\cr
~=~&f(-r)I(-r)\cr
~\stackrel{(2)+(3)}{=}~&\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}\cos(\omega r)\frac{1-\cos(2\omega r)}{2\omega},\end{align}\tag{1}$$
where
$$f(\theta)~:=~1_{[-r,0]}(\theta)\cos(\omega\theta)\tag{2}$$
and
$$ I(\theta)~:=~ \int_0^{\theta}\!\mathrm{d}\xi \sin(2\omega\xi)
~=~\frac{1-\cos(2\omega\theta)}{2\omega},\tag{3}$$
cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.
